# My variable is not assigned into the page that I used in file_get_contents

Tags: php, variables, variable-assignment, file-get-contents

I try to apply to seperate the view from logic concept. My issue is my variable is not assigned into the page that I used in `file_get_contents`.

my related code is:

in my `index.php`:

```
...

// analyze the url
require_once("analyzeURL.php");

// load page contents
require_once("page_contents.php");

// print page
require_once("v_header.php");
echo $content;
require_once("v_footer.php");
...
```

in my `page_contents.php`:

```
...
elseif ( isset($is_valid_article_uri) AND $is_valid_article_uri === TRUE )
// article uid variable: $article_id
// I got this info as an output of `analyze the url` process
{
    $page_title = '';
    $page_description = '';
    $page_author = '';
    $page_robots = '';

    $query = "SELECT `status`, `author`, `title`, `summary`, `sefd`, `content`, `categories`, `tags`, `publishdate` FROM `articles` WHERE `uid` = ? LIMIT 1";
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->bindParam(1, $article_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $sth->execute();
    $article = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $content = file_get_contents($content_root.'bd_unique_article.php');
}
```

in my `bd_unique_article.php`:

```
<div>
<?php echo $article["title"]; ?>
</div>
```

in a valid uri article page, php says that `$article` variable is undefined.

My question is what are my options and which option would be safest here to overcome this issue if I don't want to use `eval` command?
While saying *safest* I mean *silently at server environment* that just like using `require_once`
Also please notice that, `$article` array holds lots of info. My articles are really long.

thanks, best regards

Comment: can you do a `print_r($article)` and show the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`file_get_contents` will returns the same result as if you had loaded the page directly (as if through a web browser).  On that page, `$article` hasn't been set, so the output will be blank.

If you need the content to be displayed immediately, you can simply `include` the page.  If you need the content to be displayed later on, you can use [`ob_start`](http://php.net/ob_start) to buffer the output, `include` the page, then [`ob_end_clean`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to fetch and store the result.

Comment: `file_get_contents` returns the **raw content of the file**, no evaluation of its content takes place at all!

Comment: @deceze - If the path is a file system path, yes, but it also works on URLs which will evaluate the content.  It's not clear from OP's question what `$content_root` points to.

Comment: I would greatly hope that the OP is reading a local file instead of an `http://` URI...